# In iOS7 UITabbarController, how to stop resetting the navigationController to root on tapping the already selected tabBarItem?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITabBarController as the rootViewController in the storyboard of an iPad app.

It contains 3 tabBarItems.

Each item holds a navigationController.So total 3 navigationControllers.

Scenario:

1. I select the 2nd tabBarItem. Then the 2nd navigationController will become visible on the tabBarController with the view of its associated rootController.
2. I push some controllers on this visible navigationController.
3. Now, when I tap of the 2nd tabBarItem ( which is already selected now ), the tabBarController pops-up all the pushed controllers and brings the navigationController to its rootController view.

Question:
How can I stop this behaviour ? A selected tabBarItem should not do any action when the user taps on it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you init the `UITabBarController` in rootViewController add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in rootViewController, and implement this delegate:

`- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController* selected = [tabBarController selectedViewController];

    if (viewController == selected)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate for your UITabBarController to reach any behavior you want. ( **UITabBarControllerDelegate**)

And then implement delegate methods

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
            animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC{
    return self;
}
-(NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{

    return 0.25f;
}

-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{

    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;

  //Custom transition method.


    [self executePresentationAnimation:transitionContext];
}
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html